# Mac OSX Mountain Lion Rails Postgres (wiped out a lot of stuff)

Tags: postgresql, osx-mountain-lion

Having trouble with Postgres since I upgraded to Mountain Lion (and now regretting it). Lost hours trying to fix it to no avail.

When running `rails server` then visiting my app at 0.0.0.0:3000 I get this error.

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory. Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

tried updating xcode.

Comment: Can you verify that postgres is in fact running?

Comment: 'ps aux | grep postgres' yields '1870   0.0  0.0  2432768    596 s002  S+    1:38AM   0:00.01 grep postgres'

Comment: That would suggest that postgres is not running (the only output is the `grep` command itself). So maybe you need to reinstall PostgreSQL?

Comment: maybe. i know that mac osx mountain lion has it by default, but how to set that up with rails isn't clear to me. gonna try brew install postgresql and see what happens.

Comment: did brew install postgresql and still have the same error